# Can a specialized template method bypass the default one that would not compile due to the creation of an abstract object?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, c++-templates

It might be a weird question, but it could be quite handy in my use case.

I have the generic class:

```
template <typename CGtObj>
class CGtObjectsMap
{
    virtual CGtObj* newGtObject(GtId idXML, const CSAXElement *) const { return new CGtObj(idXML); } //!< can be overwritten by MyAbstractClass ;)
    virtual void loadFromXml(CSAXElement const* element);
};
```

with a "quite complex" `loadFromXml(CSAXElement const* element)` that has at one point:

```
template <typename CGtObj>
void CGtObjectsMap<CGtObj>::loadFromXml(const CSAXElement *element)
{
    ...
    objPtr = newGtObject(idXML, element);//new CGtObj(idXML);
    ...
}
```

A certain class I need to use in that `CGtObjectsMap` is abstract. That is why I've created the virtual method `newGtObject`, hoping I could avoid duplicating the whole code of `loadFromXml()` in a specialization of that class.

But it doesn't compile, and I'm having an error on the template standard definition of `newGtObject()`:

> error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘MyAbstractClass’

coming from:

```
virtual CGtObj* newGtObject(GtId idXML, const CSAXElement *) const { return new CGtObj(idXML); } //!< can be overwritten by MyAbstractClass ;)
```

although I've specialized it:

```
template<>
MyAbstractClass *CGtObjectsMap<MyAbstractClass>::newGtObject(GtId idXML, const CSAXElement *element) const
{
    MyAbstractClassType type = static_cast<MyAbstractClassType>(element->childValueByName(XML_TYPE).toInt());
    return MyAbstractClass::createAction(type, idXML);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that compilation issue?

(The specialization is in another file)

Comment: Did you specialize the method, or provided a different method for specialized class?
Hard to tell anything more without the MRE but to me it seems you need to use method templates, not class templates (not only at least...).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've a class template.
I'd like to do a explicit specialization for one of its method (`newGtObject`) for a certain Class (`MyAbstractClass `) hoping that this specialization  will be used in the generic template method `loadFromXml` but it doesn't seem to work.
I've even tried to create a child class inheriting from `CGtObjectsMap<MyAbstractClass>` where I would override the `newGtObject` method but it is still failing to compile.
Any idea why? This should work no?

@alagner what's MRE?

Comment: Could `newGtObject` just be pure virtual in `CGtObjectsMap`? Or do you really need `CGtObjectsMap<MyAbstractClass>` to not be abstract?

Comment: It seems like this should work. Does the code https://godbolt.org/z/Tn56ovqcG compile for you? If not, time to figure out what's different from that example.

Comment: I inherit from `CGtObjectsMap<MyAbstractClass>` and override the virtual method `newGtObject` but I'm still having a compilation error on gcc Linux.
I'll post the error when back home ;)
Well having it pure virtual would be boring, for most of my business objects, I don't need to specialize anything and I've more than 20 of them.
In that case I could also have made static methods in all my business objetcs to create a new instance, but I'm lazy and wanted to minimize the code changes.
In that case I could directly do something like this:
`    objPtr = CGtObj::newInstance(idXML, element);`

Comment: Hmm, "the specialization is in another file". Make sure a declaration of the specialization is visible to any code which might instantiate it. In this case, that would probably mean writing `template <> MyAbstractClass* CGtObjectsMap<MyAbstractClass>::newGtObject(GtId, const CSAXElement*);` immediately after the definition of `MyAbstractClass`. Or maybe even after a forward declaration of `MyAbstractClass`.

Comment: @Matthieu MRE=minimal reproducible example. Basically, provide some code that actually compiles (or doesn't, but fails to in a representative way), please ;)
After you clarified what you mean, I believe there's an issue with visibility of the specialization, but again, code should say more than words.

Comment: I think I'm doing this: https://godbolt.org/z/b8rG5Eofo
but I've the error as if `template <> Abstract* Map<Abstract>::newObject() const { return Abstract::createInstance(); }` was not defined...
I'll double check when home if this work with my compiler and what differs in my project. Thanks for the help

Comment: In fact I'm doing this: https://godbolt.org/z/aYETnf1d6
and it's failing on gcc, any idea why?

Comment: Yup, the issue there is the class gets instantiated before the specialization is declared. As the old limerick goes: When writing a specialization, / be careful about its location, / or to make it compile / will be such a trial / as to kindle its self-immolation.

Comment: the exact code is this: https://godbolt.org/z/z4q1ez9zT
so if I understand well the inheritance of the definition of my class AbMap would need to have a specific instanciation of the `newObject` ?

Comment: That way won't work because an override in another class doesn't stop the base class definition from existing - the compiler needs that virtual function definition since it might get called during a constructor or destructor.

Comment: yep I get it. I need to specialize it before the definition of the inherited class.
this is working: https://godbolt.org/z/q5cTxoM97
thanks a lot! \o/

Comment: @Matthieu `AbMap` in your code is not a template, so what are you specializing?
IMHO you should've done sth like this `template <> 
Abstract* Map<Abstract>::newObject() const { return Abstract::createInstance(); }` https://godbolt.org/z/enG3bdqhx